# Alert não aparece

Tags: javascript, html

Bom já tentei de tudo que sei pra resolver isso, mas não consegui, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Ao clicar no "Boleto" e selecionar uma quantidade, clicando no Finalizar, ocorreria uma ação onde é pega a quantidade que foi escolhida e multiplicada por 32, depois ela deveria retornar ao "return" e vir no alert. Segue o código:

```js
function valorAPagar(){
 var j = 0;
 if(document.getElementById("forma1").checked==true){
  j = (document.getElementById("inte") * 32);
  return j;
    }
  alert(valorAPagar());
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="forma1" value="Boleto">Boleto<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="forma2" value="Cartão de Crédito">Cartão de Crédito<br>
Entrada Inteira: <input type="number" id="inte"><br>
Meia Entrada: <input type="number" id="mei"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Finalizar" onClick="valorAPagar()">`
```

Comment: O return encerra a função e não chega no alert que vem depois. Se chegar ao alert, vai dar um loop infinito porque vc está chamando a própria função dentro dela mesma.

Comment: Certo, sendo assim o que eu poderia fazer pra ter esse alert na tela com o resultado(valor) a pagar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo 2 problemas básicos no código:

1) Se o box do boleto for marcado, nunca irá chegar no alert porque o return encerra a função. E mesmo se chegar, irá gerar um loop infinito, porque o alert está dentro da função e está chamando a própria função.

2) Falta pegar o value em `document.getElementById("inte")` para multiplicar por `32`: `document.getElementById("inte").value * 32`.

A solução que enxergo é retirar o `return j` e colocar `alert(j)`:

```js
function valorAPagar(){
   var j = 0;
   if(document.getElementById("forma1").checked==true){
      j = (document.getElementById("inte").value * 32);
   }
   alert(j);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="forma1" value="Boleto">Boleto<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="forma2" value="Cartão de Crédito">Cartão de Crédito<br>
Entrada Inteira: <input type="number" id="inte"><br>
Meia Entrada: <input type="number" id="mei"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Finalizar" onClick="valorAPagar()">
```

Comment: Desculpaa kskss, a trouxa aqui colocou o códio, mas não salvou, dor de cabeça danada já, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Essencialmente voce esta fazendo um loop infinito, no final de `valorAPagar` voce chama de novo `valorAPagar` que quando termina chama de novo `valorAPagar`, e assim por diante.

Outro problema era que na hora de pegar a qtd da inteira, estava errado, o `document.getElementById("inte")` retorna um [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), e nao o valor do input, e esse objeto tem a propriedade `value` que ai sim é o valor do input.

```js
function valorAPagar(){
  var j = 0;
  if(document.getElementById("forma1").checked==true){
    j = (document.getElementById("inte").value * 32);
    alert('Voce vai pagar '+j);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="forma1" value="Boleto">Boleto<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="forma2" value="Cartão de Crédito">Cartão de Crédito<br>
Entrada Inteira: <input type="number" id="inte"><br>
Meia Entrada: <input type="number" id="mei"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Finalizar" onClick="valorAPagar()">`
```